# Angular scope inside ng-click is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I have a `ng-repeat` which is displaying a list of hotels from a [json](/questions/tagged/json)response.  This works fine, but when i come to place a scope data inside an `ng-click` it isn't working as expected.

I am using:

```
ng-click="quick_view('{{hotel.hotel_id}}')"
```

My function is inside the correct controller as is as follows:

```
$scope.quick_view = function (hotel_id) {
$scope.hotel = hotel_id;
```

(Hotel ID is 140) so naturally, i would expect 140 to pass to the function quick_view and display '140' when i call `{{hotel}}`.  Instead, what is being displayed is `"{{hotel.hotel_id}}"`.

Any ideas why this is going wrong?

Many thanks, as usual.

Comment: Can you update the question with the json data and the html markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{{}} is an Angular expression where you can show data stored in `$scope`.

Change `ng-click="quick_view('{{hotel.hotel_id}}')"` to `ng-click="quick_view(hotel.hotel_id)"`.

Comment: Ah, this works.  Removing the '' and {{}} does the job.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, in this case, when you need to use a $scope function inside ng-repeat, you need to use only the current object with an attribute, without {{}} expression.